# How to delete the zip files except last few, in multiple folder hierarchy

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Folder structure goes like this:

```
Main_Folder:
           A
             --> File1.zip
             --> File2.zip
             A11
                --> File3.zip
                --> File4.zip
             A12
                --> File5.zip
                --> File6.zip
           B
           C
```

Similary, this remains same for B, B11 , B12 & C, C11 , C12 respectively.
I want to execute the command from Main_Folder path, such that it traverses into rest all inner folders and deletes all zip files except last few zip files.
Could you please help me out to achieve this ?

I tried

```
find $PWD -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n" | sort -n | grep "zip" | head -n -5| xargs rm -rf
```

But this keeps latest files overall, not folder by folder.

Comment: you better consider writing a bash script to loop through all the directories. One liner will be complicated. check http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/

Answer (score 0):

You usually choose some time that you want times kept.

```
# DANGEROUS!!!
$ find PATH -mtime +2 -name "*.zip" -delete
```

But you wont be sure that there are enough files kept. e.g. if your backup stopped 2 days ago, you may remove your last backups.

For it is good to first check you have enough backups. e.g.

```
existing=`find PATH -mtime -2 | wc -l`
if (( existing > 5 )); then
  find ... -delete
fi
```

Please test code very carefully before running. I did not check syntax and calculations of the snippets above. Commands a re dangerous to run. Use common sense.

HTH

Now I see you want to remove folders. Then you can search for `-mtime ... -type d` and use above logic. But insted of `-delete` you'd use something like `-exec rm -rf \{\} \;` which is even more dangerous.

Or you can get a list of folders and then delete zip files over them. It really depends on specific use case.

Comment: Currently, i'm following the same approach. Reading the paths from separate file & then check the count & then delete files. But the  path file keeps on increasing. How would you optimize it ?

Comment: @User, if you use the approach to list directories by modification time instead of individual files (I would also suggest using the `-maxdepth` option to avoid matching sub-directories), then you can use `rm -rf` to remove the whole directory.
Alternatively you can have a separate process that goes over directories and removes empty ones after the script has removed zip files. But that sounds less reliable to me. You shouldn't be storing any other files in the directories provided you want they to disappear at some point.